# How to maintain DataList item index across Postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to retain the index of the Datalist item on page reload. I'm trying to do this by storing the index into a Session and then setting the index of DataList object equals to the Session. Here's the HTML code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="MyList" Width="100%" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server"
                            OnItemDataBound="MyList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="MyList_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 5%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_isread" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isread") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_vd" runat="server" class="chkitem" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 15%;">
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="usr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("from") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 62%;">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="sub" Text='<%# Eval("subject") %>' CommandName="select" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 18%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Added") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 5%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_isread" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isread") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_messagetype" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("messagetype") %>'
                                                Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_groupid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("groupid") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_content_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content_id") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_sendertype" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sendertype") %>' Visible="false" />
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_vd" runat="server" class="chkitem" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 15%;">
                                            <uc1:avator ID="avt" runat="server" UserName='<%# Eval("from") %>' PhotoName="" Width="65"
                                                Height="65" />
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="usr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("from") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 62%;">
                                            <div class="item_pad_4">
                                                <h3 id="s_sub" runat="server">
                                                    <%# Eval("subject") %>
                                                </h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("body") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            <div class="bx_br_tp item_pad_4">
                                                <div class="btn-group" id="<%# Eval("id") %>">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="a" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="r" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" runat="server" />
                                                    <%--                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_spam" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" runat="server"
                                                        Text="spam" CommandName="spam"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 18%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Added") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </SelectedItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

On the server side, I'm trying to restore the index of the DataList item as follows:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Session["datalist"] != null)
        {
            ((DataList)Session["datalist"]).SelectedIndex = (int)Session["index"];
        }
```

Here's the function which does data binding :

```
   protected void MyList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session["datalist"] = source;
    string cmd = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandName;
    long messageid = long.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_id")).Text);
    string username = ((HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("usr")).Text;

    // approve / ignore action related values
    long content_id = 0;
    long groupid = 0;
    int messagetype = 0;

    int index = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    Session["index"] = index;
    index = (int)Session["index"];
    switch (cmd)
    {
        case "select":
            ((DataList)source).SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            int isread = int.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_isread")).Text);
            // mark message as read it its unread message
            if (isread == 0)
            {
                isread = 1; // message is read
                MailBoxBLL.Update_isRead(messageid, isread, Page.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            string _cache = "usr_msg_cnt_" + UserName;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[_cache] != null)
            {
                Cache.Remove(_cache);
            }
            break;
```

This doesn't work and Datalist item does not get selected when the page reloads. How can I make it work?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried including an UpdatePanel control + AsyncPostBackTrigger Class?

Answer (score 0):

Add this directly in Page Load:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["datalist"] != null)
         ((DataList)Session["datalist"]).SelectedIndex = (int)Session["index"];
}
```

The probelm with your code is that the `Page.IsPostBack` property will be `false` in the initial get request and for every page reload (actual postback) it will be true. Thus `!Page.IsPostBack` will become actually **false** and your code will never execute.

Comment: When I refresh the page, Page.IsPostBack is false and the code inside it execute However when I select the DataList item, Page.IsPostBack is true.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba - What do you mean by page refresh? as in when your press `F5`?

Comment: Yeah. Post.IsPostBack is true when there's a Get request. The code inside (!Page.IsPostBack ) get's executed.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba - Okay then you can handle this situation with _HttpModules_ but there is one more alternative not to check the `Page.IsPostBack` itself and just rely on value present in `Session["datalist"]` and set it when it is not null. But you will have to carefully reset it when not required. Also since it is on the same page there is no need to use `Session` variable you can do it with _HiddenVariable_ or _ViewState_ also.